# Test methods using Junit in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am trying to write some unit tests for a `spring` project. Here is the class I want to test and the test:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeManager implements QuestionDAO {

    private Manager manager;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Category getSpecificCategory(Employee employee) {
        return employee.getCategory();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/config.xml" })
public class EmployeeManagerTest extends MockObjectTestCase {

    private EmployeeManager employeeManager;

    @Autowired
    private Manager manager;

    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        this.manager = mock(Manager.class);
        this.employeeManager = new EmployeeManager(manager);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSpecificCategory() {
        this.employeeManager.getSpecificCategory(new Employee("john","developer"));
    }
}
```

When running the test above I get

```
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/config]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/config.xml]
```

In the `pom.xml` I added the dependencies for `junit` and `spring-test`.

Answer (score 1):

It's look like your 'config.xml' is not a spring xml configuration : "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/config" is not a namespace valid in this context.